# Loading 3rd party scripts in an Angular typescript project build with Webpack

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-2

I have an Angular project that makes use of Typescript and Webpack. It's a default Angular project template that comes with Visual Studio 2017.

It basically gives you a simple web application with a few NPM modules installed, like `bootstrap` and `jquery`.

I have an "3rd party" javascript file that can't be installed with NPM or Bower, but it does need jQuery.

The web application loads a `main-client.js` and  `main-client.vendor.js`. Both are created by Webpack. The last one contains the code for Bootstrap, jQuery etc.

The scripts are included like this in my webpage (I actually have more scripts):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/main-client.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/main-client.vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/plugins/custom.jqueryfile.js"></script>
```

But the web page keeps giving me the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Below are some images that shows how the script order is setup in my project.

All files are loaded in correct order
[image]

[image]

[image]

So basically my question is: How can I load "3rd party" scripts properly that need to be loaded "globally", but also require `jQuery`. Is there a general place in my Typescript files somewhere? Or can it be done with Webpack?

Comment: Do you have jQuery as the first `<script>`? Do you use `$` in your project?

Comment: No I don't have jQuery in a `script` tag. Is that really needed? Doesn't the `vendor.js` have jquery already in it. Since I `import bootstrap` in my `.ts` file (bootstrap automatically includes jquery, right?).

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you simply don't have `jQuery` included in your project. You can look for `node_modules/jquery` directory or type `jQuery` in console to check it.

As you can see in Bootstrap's [package.lock](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/package.json) file, jQuery appears only as a peer dependency.

If the 3rd party scripts you want to use have to be defined before webpack's vendor output, then I'd suggest to add usual script tag at the beginning of your `index.html`:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

You can also try just `npm i jquery` (don't forget `--save` flag for npm versions < 5). The plugins should wait for jQuery initialization, so it can also make it work. But then you also need to `import 'jquery';` in your entry file.